# InstaPy error, can't follow or unfollow users "~user is inaccessible"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram, instapy

I've installed Instapy dependency from https://pypi.org/project/instapy/ and I really enjoyed it.
There are two operations I really can't figure out why it's not working, I've followed the oficial documentation to do it, youtube videos and it isn't working.

Actually the warning message says the **user is not acessible**, but I don't know why, every user happen this, so **I can't unfollow the unfollowers**:

```
INFO [2022-02-11 20:05:41] [gorilafreela]  Ongoing Unfollow [1/3]: now unfollowing 'b'antonio_fpessoa''...
WARNING [2022-02-11 20:06:35] [gorilafreela]  --> Couldn't unfollow 'antonio_fpessoa'!  ~user is inaccessible
```

The same issue happen if I try to follow someone new, happens the same warning I said before.

```
import json
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run
import userData
import util
from selenium import webdriver

# data
userInfo = userData.getUserPassword()

# session
session = InstaPy(username=userInfo['user'], password=userInfo['password'])
session.login()

session.unfollow_users(amount=3,nonFollowers=True,unfollow_after=10,sleep_delay=60)
session.end()
```

Anyone has any ideia how can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/issues/6492)

Comment: but this issue hasn't been closed yet, I hope they're gonna solve it soon

Comment: After Tim being almost sued it by FB to stop working on it and IG changing a good part of it is data structure afterwards, I don't know how quickly the community will be able to fix the latest issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works modifying xpath_compile.py file with :

```
xpath["get_following_status"] = {
"follow_button_XP": "//button**/div/div**[text()='Following' or \
                              text()='Requested' or \
                              text()='Follow' or \
                              text()='Follow Back' or \
                              text()='Unblock' and not(ancestor::*/@role = 'presentation')]",
"follow_span_XP_following": "//button/div/span[contains(@aria-label, 'Following')]",
```

}

The issue was cause by IG changes in format of the "Follow" button. It was a `<button>Follow</button>` format and now it seems to be a `<button><div><div>Follow</div></div></button>` which the bot has to locate...